# How to add space between text using javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to add space between text like:

frequency47 = frequency 47
power250 = power 250
voltage85 = voltage 85
CompatibilityCisco = Compatibility Cisco
colourGrey = colour Grey
typePower = type Power

```html
<div id="tab-content">
  <p>
    AC input frequency47 – 63 Hz <br> 
    Total power250 W <br> 
    AC input voltage85 – 264 V <br> 
    Other features <br> 
    CompatibilityCisco ASR 1001-X <br>
    Design <br> 
    Product colourGrey <br> 
    Features <br>
    Product typePower supply <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried yourself in order to solve the problem. Remember that SO is here to help you debug issues with your code, not to write code for you.

Comment: What is the criteria you are using to identify the word needs to process and add space?

Comment: Actually I'm working on woocommerce site. I was coping product specs from  docx file and when I paste it in my site it removed some space between text. At first I didn't check the specs if it is going right or not. After when i finished entering products specs and reviewed them it was showing like that. It is gonna take much time to edit all products again to add some space so that is why i asked so @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with `replaceAll` to achieve this:

```
line.replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z0-9])/g, '$1 $2')
```

Examples:

```js
console.log('aG a7'.replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z0-9])/g, '$1 $2'));
```

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#tab-content p');

text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replaceAll(/([a-z])([A-Z0-9])/g, '$1 $2');
```

```html
<div id="tab-content">
  <p>
    AC input frequency47 – 63 Hz <br> 
    Total power250 W <br> 
    AC input voltage85 – 264 V <br> 
    Other features <br> 
    CompatibilityCisco ASR 1001-X <br>
    Design <br> 
    Product colourGrey <br> 
    Features <br>
    Product typePower supply <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want to do?

`<br` tag breaks the line, it doesn't add space between two words per se, and it's not meant for that. To do What you want, you can use `span` element, for example.

You wrap the elements you want to space out within a `span` and using `CSS` you add some margin, or padding.

Notice that `span` elements are `inline` elements so by default they only accept margin horizontally (left and right), to add margin to them from top and bottom, you have to make their display to be `inline-block` or `block` or just use `p` tag at that point.

```css
#tab-content span {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab-content">
  <p>
    AC input frequency<span>47</span> – 63 Hz<br>
    Total power<span>250 W</span><br>
    AC input voltage<span>85</span> – 264 V <br> 
    Other features <br> 
    Compatibility<span>Cisco ASR<span>1001-X</span> <br>
    Design <br> 
    Product colour<span>Grey</span> <br> 
    Features <br>
    Product type<span>Power</span> supply <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Although, if you just want a single regular space between those words I don't understand why not just add a space between those words when you are writing the `HTML`. However, this approach gives you much more flexibility and power over how you space those words (in this example).

Comment: This means the user would have to change the html manually, and if he can that then why not add the space instead of a span???

Comment: Then I don't see the point in your answer. making a "false" space is not a good way to do stuff, for many many reason.